# Long Receiving Time Only in FF not IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, spring-restcontroller

I have had this unusual problem with my Spring rest server for a couple of months where performance with Firefox (52.0.1 32-bit and 64-bit) is much much worse than with Internet Explorer (9-11) when receiving large amounts of JSON data.

The server that is hosting my service is a Windows Server Enterprise 2007 SP2.
If I could, I would update it, but that is not allowable.

To further define my problem, making a request to an endpoint to retrieve the JSON data results in an almost immediate response in Firefox, but it is stuck in "Receiving" for sometimes in upwards of 90 seconds.  Internet Explorer typically is done in 2-3 seconds.  (See photo below of network output from FF)

[image]

I have a feeling that this may be a server problem because previous to this service being hosted on this server, it was being hosted from a linux vm while we were deving and testing the service.  During that time the response time with FF and IE were both the same and very quick (in fact the same response time as IE has now).

I tagged `javascript` in this not to tag spam, but because when the data comes back it does go through some rigorous transformations in the JS and I'm not sure if that is contributing to the problem.  (This is doubtful though just because if IE can handle it FF should being that Mozilla deved JS)

My question is:  Would you say this problem is related to the server, JS implementation, or something else? and what might I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Let's start with: what have you tried to narrow down the problem? I don't recognize the style of this bar graph, did you check the dev-tools in you browser to determine what is taking 86 seconds, the actual request, the response or processing the received data? what kind of data does the request/response contain *(raw / JSON / url encoded / ...)*, and how much of that *(in bytes / KB / MB / GB)*?

Comment: @Thomas  So the bar graph is from the network tab in firefox.  When you click on a network request, on the right there are 5 tabs, one of them is timings.  This is where the screen shot was taken.  The 86 seconds is the response. Although, while it is still receiving the data, I can inspect the network request and see the response headers.  The data being transmitted is around 12 MBs of JSON

Comment: OK, didn't recognize it. `The data being transmitted is around 12 MBs of JSON` that's probably the problem. That's A LOT of string that needs to be parsed. Just made a test, it took my laptop almost 5 minutes just to parse that amount of JSON in FF. Can you break down the data into multiple chunks?

Comment: @Thomas No, unfortunately the amount of requests to the server needs to be limited.  It is just strange that it doesn't have a problem with it in IE and when it was running on a linux vm FF would receive it in less than 2 seconds.

Comment: different implementations of the JSON class. 2 seconds sounds like native code whereas these 2 minutes sounds like an implementation in JS to me. Can you show the structure of the data? The idea is to implement a different/custom parser. This might take even a bit longer to parse completely, but It could flush intermediate/partial results to be processed and shown to the user. Whereas at the moment you have to wait till all the work is done by `JSON.parse()`.

Comment: @Thomas Structure is what you might expect like so: `[ {key:value,key:value} , {key:value...etc` or did I misunderstand your request for the structure of the data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138944/discussion-between-thomas-and-craigr8806).